# How to run a fallback upon multiple Axios calls?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

In my app, a comment can be a parent and have child comments. When deleting a parent comment, I'm checking whether children exists; and if so, I'm deleting them too (each with one separate `Axios` call).

But I need to run some refresh code once all of this is done. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Where can I place my refresh code?

Here is my code so far:

```
deleteCommentAxiosCall (id) {
  return this.$axios.delete(`/api/v1/comment/${this.comment.id}`)
},
deleteComment () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.deleteCommentAxiosCall(this.comment.id)
    if (this.comment.child_comments.length) {
      this.comment.child_comments.forEach((child) => {
        this.deleteCommentAxiosCall(child.id)
      })
    }
  })
  window.location.reload() // refresh code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to chain the promises to ensure the deletions are resolved before refreshing. Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await several promises at once. In this case, you'd await the deletion of the parent comment along with the child comments.

```
deleteComment () {
  return Promise.all([
    this.deleteCommentAxiosCall(this.comment.id),
    this.comment.child_comments.map(child => this.deleteCommentAxiosCall(child.id))
  ])
  .then(() => window.location.reload())
}
```

Or with an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async deleteComment () {
  await Promise.all([
    this.deleteCommentAxiosCall(this.comment.id),
    this.comment.child_comments.map(child => this.deleteCommentAxiosCall(child.id))
  ])
  window.location.reload()
}
```

Also: Reloading the page might be somewhat jarring to the user. Perhaps a more seamless way of refreshing the comments is to re-request the comments via an explicit API request. Example:

```
this.$axios.get(`/api/v1/comments`).then(resp => this.comments = resp.data.comments)
```

Comment: Double thanks, for the right answer and the secondary advice which is actually pretty good!

Comment: @drake035 No problem :)